# How to csv-import cyrillic text into latin1-swedish-ci encoded table in PhpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, csv, utf-8, phpmyadmin

How to csv-import cyrillic text into latin1-swedish-ci encoded table in PhpMyAdmin?

My problem:

Everything works fine with front-end. But now I need to import ~1000 rows in a table. I'd prefer UTF-8, but the table is in latin1-swedish-ci. When I even prepare my CSV in latin1-swedish-ci, there is no such option in the PhpMyAdmin import settings.

[image]

Comment: I would not expect latin1-swedish-ci to have codepoints for most Cyrillic characters.

Answer (score 0):

First, keep in mind that the encoding of the file and the `CHARACTER SET` of the column/table do not need to be the same.

Second, `latin1` *cannot* represent Cyrillic.  Perhaps [`cp1251`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) has what you need.  Caution:  I think it can handle only English and Russian, not the rest of Europe.

`UTF-8` (MySQL's utf8mb4) is the way to go.  This will involve 2 *bytes* per Cyrillic *character*.

Before mangling things worse, find out what the encoding of your data is.  The HEX for `Д` (Capital DE):

```
C4 -- in cp1251 aka ISO/IEC 8859-5
D094 -- in utf8 or utf8mb4
```